# Unable to copy multiple files to a directory using Perl script

Tags: perl, bash

One wierd behaviour I am observing -- in a perl script , I checked wether a directory exists or not, if it exists - it copies a file to that directory, if it doesnt -then the directory is created followed by the file copy

When I go and check the file manually, the file is present . but when I run the same script again to copy another file using the same process as above, I see that the previous files arent present. For a confirmation , I performed a directory read in the script , it said that dir is empty.

Can anyone please help me in understanding

Please find below a code :

```
if (-d "/home/foo") {

  print "the directory is already created \n";
  $i=0;
  opendir(DIR, "/home/foo") or die "Cant open /home/foo: $!\n";
  @list = readdir(DIR);

  foreach $line(@list) {
    unless ($line =~ /^[.][.]?\z/) {
      $i++;
    }
  }

  if ($i != 0) { print "There is Stuff in here!"; } 
  else         { print "This Dir is Empty!"; }
  closedir(DIR);
}
else {
  &runcond("mkdir /home/foo");
}

`cp $file /home/foo`;  #Copying a file $file in the directory
```

Comment: `/^[.][.]?\z/` == `/^\.{1,2}$/`. Its much more readable. `if ($i != 0) ` == `if ($i)`

Comment: could be the `\z` in your Regex

Comment: `my $bool = grep /^\.\.?\z/, readdir(DIR);`

Comment: totally out of loop : why implement `bash copy` in code when [perl copy command](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) is there?

Answer (score 0):

```
`cp $file /home/foo`;
```

You haven't defined `$file`